# How to make a UIView move all the time?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to animate an object for as long as the app is running.
This doesn't seem to work:

```
for (int i = -100; i < 200; i++) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [_targetView setFrame:CGRectMake(i, _targetView.frame.origin.y, _targetView.frame.size.width, _targetView.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (i == 200) {
        [self anotherLoopThatGoesBackFrom200to-100];
    }
}
```

_targetView is a UIView placed at the bottom of the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a single animation that moves your view from one side of the screen to the other. Set this to auto repeat and auto reverse:

```
// Assume your view starts with a center of 50,50
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    view.center = CGPointMake(270,50);
} completion:nil];
```

This is using the block-based syntax which is recommended over the type used in your question.

You'll need to tweak the center and timing values to suit your purpose. You can also add in timing curves to make the animation more interesting, just `|` in a curve option (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions) for examples).

Answer (score 1):

**Why doesn't this work?**

```
for (int i = -100; i < 200; i++) {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[_targetView setFrame:CGRectMake(i, _targetView.frame.origin.y , _targetView.frame.size.width, _targetView.frame.size.height)];
[UIView commitAnimations];

if (i == 200) {
    [self anotherLoopThatGoesBackFrom200to-100];
}
```

}

When you commit animations in the current run loop, they are not executed immediately. You've create 300 animations in a row and then asked the runtime to perform them - it will perform the last one you ask it too, as it doesn't have time to do the previous ones before you overwrite it. You want to be setting up a chain of animations. There is a method that will take a completionBlock, a chunk of code that will happen after the current animation completes: you should use that.

You are also approaching this in the wrong way sorry: don't set the frame for each stage of the animation - this is what `UIKit` is going to handle for you! It will adapt for framerate changes, create KVO notifications and make this a lot simpler.

Set the start frame before the animation block, the put the final position inside the animation block. The animation will occur naturally

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, here are two. First, you could use the `animateWithDuration: completion:` class method of `UIView` like this

```
 -(void) animateBlueRect {

     _block WhateverClassThisIs selfReference = self; 
     void (^animationBlock) () = ^void {

           _targetView.frame = //whatever 
     };
     [UIView animateWithDuration: someDuration animations: animationBlock completion: ^(BOOL finished) {

         [selfReference animateBlueRect]
    }];
}
```

Alternatively you could use a `CADDisplayLink`, and keep track of how far your rect had moved in a property used in its callback like so:

```
 //inside your .h file, or a class extension in your .m
 @property (assign) float currFramePos;

 //inside your setup method
 CADisplayLink link =  [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget: self selector: blueRectMover];
 [link addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]

 //a seperate method
 -(void) blueRectMover
 {
     currFramePos++;
     if (currFramePos > 200) {
       _targetView.frame = CGRectMake(currFramePos, 0, 100, 100)
     }

      else {_targetView.frame = CGRectMake(-100, 0, 100, 100); 

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.
                      delay:0.
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
    _bouncingView.frame = frame;
} completion:nil];
```

or

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"bounce" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:10.];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
_bouncingView.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sprite Kit

If you're looking into making games, I suggest you looking into Sprite Kit that comes with iOS 7 (There's even a template project).

With SpriteKit you can add and chain actions together to describe behavior:

```
SKAction *right = [SKAction moveToX:self.size.width duration:2.0];
SKAction *left  = [SKAction moveToX:0.0             duration:2.0];

SKAction *moveLeftAndRight = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[right, left]]];

[sprite runAction:moveLeftAndRight];
```

### CAAnimation

If you don't like the idea of using SpriteKit, and want to do something adhoc, look into `CoreAnimation`. Link and import `QuartzCore` (linking unnecessary on iOS 7):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And then add the animation:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];

animation.keyTimes      = @[@(0.0), @(0.5), @(1.0)];
animation.values        = @[@(0.0),@(320.0),@(0.0)];
animation.duration      = 0.5;
animation.repeatCount   = HUGE_VALF;

[_targetView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"bounceLeftRight"];
```